# can't unbind mouse leave when clicking

Tags: jquery, binding, click, mouseevent

I have a jquery script, where if you mouseenter and element, something shows, and disappears when you mouseleave. I'm trying to unbind the mouseleave when user clicks, so that "something" stays showing when user leaves. Is this the correct way to do it? If so, can someone help me get this script to work?

Thank you!

```
$('.block').live("mouseenter",function(){
        var id= $(this).attr('id');
        $('#arrowPreview'+id).show();


    }).live("mouseleave",function(){
        var id= $(this).attr('id');
        $('#arrowPreview'+id).hide();

    }).live("click",function(){
        var id= $(this).attr('id');
        $('#arrowPreview'+id).show();
        $(this).unbind("mouseleave");
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: You must use `die()` to unbind live event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't think what you want is exactly possible. The problem appears to be the use of `.live` and unbind. You can unbind the mouseleave event with `.die`. However, the selector used must match the one originally used to bind the event, in your case `.block`. I am thinking that this obviously is bad. Example Fiddle of .die

http://jsfiddle.net/EZNDg/

I think that instead you need to bind using an explicit selector for the current element, so perhaps using `.each` with your selector and then binding with $(this). This should allow die to work. I will mess with this Fiddle and see if it is true.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the functions to execute on events as variables to ensure integrity of your javascript so for your example:

```
var fShow = function(){
    var id= $(this).attr('id');
    $('#arrowPreview'+id).show();
};

var fHide = function(){
    var id= $(this).attr('id');
    $('#arrowPreview'+id).hide();
};

var fClick = function(){        
    var id= $(this).attr('id');
    $('#arrowPreview'+id).show();
};

$('.block').bind('mouseenter',fShow);
$('.block').bind('mouseleave',fHide);
$('.block').unbind('mouseleave',fHide);
```

Comment: i believe this is the same as my script, just written in a different way

Comment: Yeah, goal of script is the same as your original but implementation is different.  Refer to http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ for specifics on why yours doesn't work.  Bind/unbind as function variable as opposed to anonymous function causes problems.

Comment: Works for me, must be something specific to your implementation.  Sorry couldn't be of further help.  Good luck, read link from previous comment.

Comment: live != bind, if the elements don't exist at time of selection, bind wont be of use.

Answer (score 0):

events bound with [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) are unbound with [`die`](http://api.jquery.com/die/)