# binding back after die using live?

Tags: jquery, function, binding, click, mouseevent

I didn't mean it to rhyme!

But I need help. I have done some live function events with jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave, and click. If mouseenter an element, another element shows, and if mouseleaves, that element disappears. If clicked, the element is still shown, and mouseleaves dies.

Now, my question is, how do you rebind how make that element disappear when you click again.

```
$('.block').live("mouseenter",function(){
        var id= $(this).attr('id');
        $('#arrowPreview'+id).show();


    }).live("mouseleave",function(){
        var id= $(this).attr('id');
        $('#arrowPreview'+id).hide();

    }).live("click",function(){
        var id= $(this).attr('id');
        $('#arrowPreview'+id).show();
        $('.block').die("mouseleave");
    });
```

Thats my script so far. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't unbind mouse leave when clicking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734602/cant-unbind-mouse-leave-when-clicking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the `mouseleave` handler on the clicked element, and instead change a piece of state information attached to the element when it is clicked so you know that the `mouseleave` event should perform no action.

```
var blocks = $('.block');

blocks.live("mouseenter",function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#arrowPreview'+id).show();
}).live("mouseleave",function(){
  var obj = $(this);
  if (!obj.data('inactive')) {
    var id = obj.attr('id');
    $('#arrowPreview'+id).hide();
  }
}).live("click",function(){
  var obj = $(this);
  var id = obj.attr('id');
  $('#arrowPreview'+id).show();
  obj.data('inactive', !obj.data('inactive'));
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D9zaK/5/

Comment: the demo doesn't seem to work in my case. If user clicks again, it doesn't disappear

Comment: ah I misunderstood part of your question. try now, new link: http://jsfiddle.net/D9zaK/5/

Comment: Quick question. If I'm click on by "id", if I click another element with a different "id", how do I make my previous click disappear?

Comment: for instance, in your jsfiddle. If I click on AAA box, it shows, and disappears how we want to. But if you click on AAA box and then click on BBB box, AAA box and BBB box shows. But how do you element the AAA box when you click on BBB box. (But also keeping all the other requirements) So the user would be able to hide the previous clicks.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be not to call `die()` in the first place. Instead, you can store the "clicked" state in the document's [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and only hide the element in your `mouseleave` handler if the "clicked" state allows it.

**EDIT:** From the requirements in your latest comment, it looks like you want the "clicked" state to be maintained for each element instead of globally (which means `die()` wasn't the way to go in the first place, because it unbinds the handler globally).

The following code hopefully fulfills your requirements:

```
$(".block").live("mouseenter", function() {
    var $arrow = $("#arrowPreview" + this.id);
    if (!$arrow.data("freeze")) {
        $arrow.show();
    }
}).live("mouseleave", function() {
    var $arrow = $("#arrowPreview" + this.id);
    if (!$arrow.data("freeze")) {
        $arrow.hide();
    }
}).live("click", function() {
    var $arrow = $("#arrowPreview" + this.id);
    $arrow.data("freeze", !$arrow.data("freeze"));
});
```

Comment: I need to hide when mouseleave if user doesn't click

Comment: @andrewliu, if the user doesn't click, then `$(document).data("preventHiding")` will evaluate to `false` and the element will be hidden. Isn't this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying this out, and when user clicks, it just stays clicked. it doesn't go away when i click again.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what chetan patel meant with his `toggle()` call. You'll have to use that instead of `show()` if you want the element to be hidden before you `mouseleave` away. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Its now giving me problems. When using mouseenter and mouseleave the first time, it works. But when I click, the element doesn't show up. But when i mouseenter, it shows up. and then when i click again and mouseleaves, the element shows. so its doing the opposite now

Comment: Well, I'm not sure to properly understand your requirements... Does removing the `!` operator in the call to `toggle()` produce the correct result?

Comment: Unfortunately its not. Hmm let me see if I can make this more clear. if user mouseenter, an arrow shows, if mouseleaves, arrows disappears. when user mouseenter and clicks, the arrows stays (even if mouseleaves). So if the arrow stays, the user would want to click again, to make it disappear. And this should continue.

Comment: @andrewliu, your requirements are indeed clearer now. I rewrote the code from scratch in order to get a simple solution that will hopefully fulfill them.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried copying and putting into my code, but it still seems like it doesn't work. however, ctcherry was able to get it to work for me. I really appreciate your time and help for this

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use die. The easy way to do it is to just set a flag. Once click is registered, flag is true. mouseleave function has a conditional to check if flag is set, and will not hide if the flag is true. Next time you click, unset the flag and either hide it right away or let mouseleave do its thing.